How can I render bodies continuously on the screen with an interval in React Native & Expo with matter .js?
I'm trying to create a simple game in React native with matter.js and react-native-game engine. I have created a bunch of shapes which I want to render continuously with a 1 second delay. The shapes are rendered properly when I create them altogether when I create a limited number of them with a loop, however when I try to do the same thing in a setInterval function I notice that the shapes are created in my logs but not rendered onscreen. How do I change my components to make sure that the shapes are rendered properly?
This is my code for my entities function where I am creating the bodies:
import Matter from 'matter-js';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

import Box from '../components/Box';
import Circle from '../components/Circle';
import Triangle from "../components/Triangle";
import Rectangle from '../components/Rectangle';
import EllipseComponent from "../components/Ellipse";
import Pentagon from "../components/Pentagon";
import Hexagon from "../components/Hexagon";

export default (gameworld) => {
    let engine = Matter.Engine.create();
    let world = engine.world;
    let { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

    const shapes = {};

    const createRandomShape = () => {
        // Choose a random shape component
        const randomShapeIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
        let shape;
        switch (randomShapeIndex) {
            case 0:
                shape = Box(
                    world,
                    'red',
                    { x: Math.random() * width, y: 120 },
                    { width: 40, height: 40 },
                    { isStatic: false, label: 'Square' }
                );
                console.log('Square rendered:');
                break;
            case 1:
                shape = Circle(
                    world,
                    'blue',
                    { x: Math.random() * width, y: 120 },
                    20,
                    { isStatic: false, label: 'Circle' }
                );
                console.log('Circle rendered:');
                break;
            case 2:
                shape = Triangle(
                    world,
                    'green',
                    { x: Math.random() * width, y: 120 },
                    { width: 50, height: 50 },
                    { isStatic: false, label: 'Triangle' }
                );
                console.log('Triangle rendered:');
                break;
            case 3:
                shape = Rectangle(
                    world,
                    'purple',
                    { x: Math.random() * width, y: 120 },
                    { width: 60, height: 40 },
                    { isStatic: false, label: 'Rectangle' }
                );
                console.log('Rectangle rendered:');
                break;
            case 4:
                shape = EllipseComponent(
                    world,
                    'orange',
                    { x: Math.random() * width, y: 120 },
                    { width: 60, height: 40 },
                    { isStatic: false, label: 'Ellipse' }
                );
                console.log('Ellipse rendered:');
                break;
            case 5:
                shape = Pentagon(
                    world,
                    'pink',
                    { x: Math.random() * width, y: 120 },
                    { width: 40, height: 40 },
                    { isStatic: false, label: 'Pentagon' }
                );
                console.log('Pentagon rendered:');
                break;
            case 6:
                shape = Hexagon(
                    world,
                    'yellow',
                    { x: Math.random() * width, y: 140 },
                    { width: 60, height: 40 },
                    { isStatic: false, label: 'Hexagon' }
                );
                console.log('Hexagon rendered:');
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return shape;
    };

    // // Generate shapes every second: THIS DOES NOT WORK
    // let shapeId = 0;
    // setInterval(() => {
    //     const newShape = createRandomShape();
    //     // Store the new shape in the shapes object with a unique ID
    //     shapes[`shape${shapeId++}`] = newShape;
    // }, 1000);

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        const newShape = createRandomShape();
        shapes[`shape${i}`] = newShape;
    }

    return {
        physics: { engine, world },
        ...shapes, // Store the shapes array in the game world
    };
};

How I'm currently passing the shapes to the GameEngine component
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, Alert, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { GameEngine } from 'react-native-game-engine';

import entities from '../entities/index';
import Physics from '../Physics';

const GameScreen = (props) => {
    const [gameEntities, setGameEntities] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        try {
            const initialEntities = entities();
            setGameEntities(initialEntities);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Failed to initialize entities:', error);
        }
    }, []);

    if (!gameEntities) {
        return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Game Screen</Text>
            <Text>Click on the button to navigate to the next screen</Text>
            <Button
                title="Go to Main Screen"
                onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('ScreenOne')}
            />
            <GameEngine
                systems={[Physics]}
                entities={gameEntities}
            >
                <StatusBar style="auto" hidden={true} />
            </GameEngine>
        </View>
    );
}

export default GameScreen;

The code for my Box component looks like this, All shapes follow a similar pattern:
import Matter from 'matter-js';

const Box = (props) => {
    const width = props.body.bounds.max.x - props.body.bounds.min.x;
    const height = props.body.bounds.max.y - props.body.bounds.min.y;

    const xPos = props.body.position.x - width / 2;
    const yPos = props.body.position.y - height / 2;

    return (
        <View
            style={{
                borderWidth: 2,
                width: width,
                height: height,
                left: xPos,
                top: yPos,
                backgroundColor: props.color,
                position: 'absolute',
            }}
        ></View>
    );
};

export default (world, color, pos, size) => {
    const theBox = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
        pos.x,
        pos.y,
        size.width,
        size.height,
        { label: 'Box', frictionAir: 0, friction: 1, isStatic: false, density: 0.001 }

    );
    Matter.World.add(world, theBox);
    console.log('Box created:');
    return { body: theBox, color, pos, renderer: <Box /> };
};```


Please show import Box from '../components/Box'; etc. Presumably that's where shapes are being added to the world. Any reason you're copying the returned array with ...shapes? I'd probably pass a reference with just plain shapes so you can add to it later, although the design doesn't seem good to me in general. You'll need some way to trigger a rerender, or use references, otherwise React won't know about the mutation in the interval.

I have updated the post to show how I'm initializing the Box  component. Sorry for the mistake I am trying to add the shape to the shapes object, according to my knowledge the GameEngine component is set up to accept only objects as part of entities.
